# How can I see the source of the current revision of an answer with a pending edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Question: https://superuser.com/questions/64808/create-your-own-hand-written-font-for-free
Answer: https://superuser.com/a/64825/36744
**edit** link: https://superuser.com/questions/64808/create-your-own-hand-written-font-for-free/64825#

[image]

So I click **edit ()**.

---

[image]

OK, that sucks. I need to pull in info from the old revision so the answer still makes sense. I click **Improve**.

---

[image]

Now there is no way to get the source of the answer! Or am I missing something?

In this case, I don't want to reject the edit. Because I would like to mark it helpful as, in general, the information was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second icon on the left allows you to view the source, you have selected the first icon which view output.

[image]

Comment: I assume this is the icon you're talking about. Even after your post it took me a couple of minutes to find it. Which is confusing because I faintly remember having used the function in the past. Thanks.